# ng-model is not updating properly

Tags: angularjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div ng-repeat='x in trail'>
<input type=checkbox ng-model='one1'>{{x}}</div>
<div  ng-repeat='x in array'>
<p ng-hide='one1' >{{x}}</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.trail = ["Volvo","bike","access","rocket"];
$scope.array = ["Volvo","bike","access","rocket"];
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run this,and click on any check box,whole array values should hide, but not hiding.

Comment: Can you write $scope.one1 = false; to your controller?

Comment: yeah,but i want to set the value of one1 using checkboxc

Comment: I got this but you need to init it before use.

Comment: $scope.trail and $scope.array having same values?

Comment: i tried@hurricane,i was not working as i want
and @nagaveer ,yes same value

Comment: Check it in the plunker added in the below answer. Why you are maintaining two arrays with same value.

Answer (score 0):

Add a variable to $scope.trail array something like "checked"

```
<input type=checkbox ng-model="x.checked">
```

You can see a [demo here](https://plnkr.co/edit/b9i604yySwNSRdKx35oK?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to hide the whole array, you can utilize `ng-change` directive passing model to it

[here is a demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/uNdmNJ6TZMMPrHESW5zE?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Actually i found a problem on your example. If you create a ng-repeat and use an input area with same scope value, array values are not equal to scope value.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.trail = ["Volvo","bike","access","rocket"];
        $scope.array = ["Volvo","bike","access","rocket"];
    $scope.one = true;
}

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="one">{{one}} {{x}}
  <div ng-repeat='x in trail'>

  </div>
  <div  ng-repeat='x in array'>
    <label ng-show="one == true" >{{x}}</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/12781/)